# How to populate a ListView when application launches?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm a newbie to Kivy, and I'm having a hard time trying to populate a view. I know I can use the `item_strings` attribute in a `kv` file, but I want to do it programmatically since I have planned to use an adapter later.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
self.name_list_screen.name_list = [str(i + 1) for i in range(10)]
```

but when I run my app, it crashes since `self.name_list_screen` is `None`.

This is my Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class SpikeRoot(BoxLayout):
    name_list_screen = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name_list_screen.name_list = [str(i + 1) for i in range(10)]



class NameListScreen(BoxLayout):
    name_list = ObjectProperty()



class SpikeApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpikeApp().run()
```

and this is my Kivy file

```
SpikeRoot:
    name_list_screen: name_list_scree_widget
    NameListScreen:
        id: name_list_scree_widget

<NameListScreen>:
    name_list: name_list_view
    ListView:
        id: name_list_view
```

Is there any method that I can call when the widgets have been loaded so I can load my this list view, i.e., at this point this list view is no longer `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was not defining the rule for `SpikeRoot`, so adding `<SpikeRoot>:` to my kivy file solved my problem. So, in the end I did no changes in my Python file, but I changed my Kivy file to this:

```
SpikeRoot:

<SpikeRoot>:
    name_list_screen: name_list_scree_widget
    NameListScreen:
        id: name_list_scree_widget

<NameListScreen>:
    name_list: name_list_view
    ListView:
        id: name_list_view
```